# How to pass data using chackboxes in HTML uiComponent

Tags: knockoutjs, checkbox

I'm trying to add/remove data based on a checkbox. I can't figure out how go get the value to get through to the function.

My console is logging a list of my observed variables.

Any idea how to pass the data that I need using checkboxes?

Thanks

My html

```
 <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="awning"
                       value="Awning"
                       checkedValue="awning"
                       click="processCheckbox.bind('awning')">
                <label for="awning">Awning</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" id="sign"
                       value="Sign"
                       checkedValue="sign"
                       click="processCheckbox.bind('sign')">
                <label for="sign">Sign</label>
            </div>
```

js

```
define(['jquery', 'uiComponent'], function ($, Component) {
    'use strict'


    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            industries: []
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            this._super().observe(['industries']);

            return this;
        },

  processCheckbox: function (value) {
            console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Where are you trying this? Phtml file? UI Components? Knockout? Checkout? etc - the more info you can give us the better

Comment: Edited with more details